# Modern results that are widely known, yet which at the time were ignored, not accepted or criticized

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list

What is your favorite example of a celebrated mathematical fact that had a hard time to become accepted by the community, but after overcoming some initial "resistance" quickly took on?

It can be a theorem, a proof method, an algorithm or a definition, that is

- widely known and
- very useful in the present day,
- less than 99 years old; this is in order to avoid examples from the very distant past, such the difficulties Grassmann's work had being accepted

but which at the time of its inception was not appreciated, misunderstood or ignored by the mathematical community, before it became mainstream or inspired other research which in turn became mainstream. This is a partial converse question to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-to-be-wrong) that asks for mathematical facts that were quickly accepted but then discarded by the community. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121565/mathematicians-whose-works-were-criticized-by-contemporaries-but-became-widely-a) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13896/what-are-some-famous-rejections-of-correct-mathematics/13975#13975) question are somewhat related, but former focuses on people (resp. their entire works, see Grassmann) not being accepted, rather then individual results, whereas the latter solely on famous articles rejected by journal; also, the results that are being mentioned in these links are often rather old and do not fit this question.

---

Example. **Numerical optimization**: The first [quasi-Newton algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method) was discovered in [1959](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/4252678) and "was not accepted for publication; it
remained as a technical report for more than thirty years until it appeared in the ﬁrst issue of the SIAM Journal on Optimization in 1991" (Nocedal & Wright, Numerical Optimization).
But the algorithm inspired a slew of other variants, has been cited over 2000 times to this day and quasi-Newton type algorithms are *still* state-of-the-art in for certain optimization problems.

Comment: Do you want to count results that were ignored, not for any real fault of the mathematical community, but because they were published in an unusual way, like the Selberg integral?

Comment: @WillSawin Being published in an unusual form makes it easy for the mathematical community to misunderstand or ignore the result (even if the mathematical community is not at fault here), so yes, I would like to count those results

Comment: The work of Heegner is mentioned elsewhere on similar MO questions, but I believe it fits here too.

Comment: @SamHopkins Feel free to post it!

Comment: Another possibility of an "ignored" result is "eigenvectors from eigenvalues": https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795.

Comment: Proof of Gaussian correlation inequality.

Comment: Does the proof of the four-color theorem qualify?

Comment: @lhf I would say no, because (at least in my ignorance, perhaps someone can educate me) I feel that the results is not really useful. It seems to stand alone, as a milestone in terms of using computers and in terms of the question being settled. It is not used over and over again as a in various proofs. (But, again, I may be wrong about this.)

Comment: @SamHopkins Eigenvectors from eigenvalues is an interesting case, but I think the main issue there was that it failed to become "widely known" as stated in the title question. So maybe it's an answer to a slightly different question. The same might be true of the Gaussian correlation inequality, though I'm less sure what I think about that one.

Comment: This one fails your 99-year criterion, but I think is otherwise an excellent example: [Why was Wantzel overlooked for a century? The changing importance of an impossibility result](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2009.03.001).

Comment: @alhal The proof of the four-color theorem yields an algorithm for finding a four-coloring of a planar graph. See for example, [Efficiently four-coloring planar graphs](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/237814.238005) by Robertson et al. Now you could argue that for practical purposes, there are simpler, heuristic algorithms that run faster and that usually find a four-coloring. But the guaranteed-to-work, quadratic-time algorithm relies on details of the proof of the four-color theorem.

Comment: @TimothyChow But still, my question remains: Where do you in your day-to-day mathematical activity, really need to rely on such an algorithm? To take the example of the umbral calculus posted below, which I feel is a good one: This is a workhorse that is constantly used in a particular area of mathematics to derive results; the four-colouring algorithm is not (as far as I know, but I don't know much about graph theory). In this precise sense I meant that is it not "useful" and that it "stands alone".

Comment: I do like the example of Wantzel's results though - even though it is also not "useful" and "stands alone". I'm conflicted about these types of results that are not "useful" and have been overlooked; perhaps a new question should be created that tailors to them specifically

Comment: @alhal To a first approximation, I use zero results in my day-to-day activity. I don't even use calculus. That doesn't mean it's not useful to *somebody*. I suspect that your own area of math doesn't require doing a lot of programming and heavy computation on a day-to-day basis. Am I right? A computational graph theorist who does a lot of experimental mathematics daily may have a different perspective on how useful a graph algorithm is.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341959/examples-of-unsuccessful-theories-with-afterlives

Comment: @alhal I should also mention that [Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) is still open, and is the subject of considerable ongoing research. This research relies on the four-color theorem. For example, the proof of the $k=6$ case of Hadwiger's conjecture explicitly relies on the four-color theorem.

Comment: This SMBC comic seems relevant: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/how-math-works

Answer (score 37):

The Selberg integral was proved in a 1944 paper of Selberg, after being stated without proof in a 1941 paper. The paper was in Norwegian, and was also in a journal that would have been of little interest to the research community:

> This paper was published with some hesitation, and in Norwegian,
> since I was rather doubtful that the results were new. The journal
> is one which is read by mathematics-teachers in the gymnasium

This result was little-used, being used in one paper in 1953.

A closely related integral then appeared in random matrix theory. Mehta and Dyson gave a conjectural value for this integral, publicizing this conjecture as an open problem in a paper in 1963, a textbook in 1967, and the SIAM Review in 1974. However, no one remembered Selberg's work and thought to apply it.

Finally in 1976 Bombieri came across another similar integral when studying a different topic (prime numbers). He went to discuss his overall work on the distribution of prime numbers with Selberg, because of Selberg's expertise in number theory, and Selberg then mentioned his integral, which Bombieri used to solve his problem.

This was after Bombieri was informed by Spencer about the relationship of his integral to a third topic (the Coulomb gas), motivating him to ask Dyson about it, at which point Dyson explained the connection to random matrices, and thus Bombieri was able to prove the conjecture in random matrix theory as well.

Since then, the result has found further use and development, and is now widely-known.

My source for all these details is the paper [The importance of the Selberg integral](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3981) by Peter J. Forrester and S. Ole Warnaar

Comment: I guess this story goes to show (among other things) how hard it can be in an age without math sci net or other scientific search engines to actually find what the state of the art is.

Comment: @alhal How much would math sci net help with this? What would you search for?

Comment: If your choice is between going to the library skimming books and papers vs. sitting at your desk and typing in keywords in search form and they again using keywords to search through a pdf - well, in the latter case you are orders of magnitudes faster (and therefore more likely) to discover what other might have published that is similar to your own stuff. Heck, even mathoverflow does a decent job highlight similar questions ...

Comment: @alhal That is not what the choice is. People did not just randomly skim books and papers before the internet came along... You would go and say your keywords to a librarian, and a skilled librarian is worth their weight in gold.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda You make unreasonable assumptions: 1) First and foremost: Few people have access to such librarians (Selberg certainly hadn't) 2) With the flood of information any single person will have a hard time to stay on top of cutting edge in more than a few subfields 3) A librarian (also) isn't a mathematical semantic search engine that can easily parse highly specialized literature for you, you still have to do that

Comment: @alhal I don’t see anywhere in my comment where I make any of those assumptions. You said “the choice is between skimming books and papers vs using search engines and pdf tools”. That this is the choice is patently false.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda You said "That is not what the choice is" and implied a different choice (namely a search engine vs having a competent libraried). I outlined why your assumed choice doesn't work.

Comment: @alhal What do you mean by “my assumed choice doesn’t work”? That’s what the choice was. You claimed that the best one could do was to “skim through papers and books” to keep up to date. This is incorrect; they used librarians. I don’t understand what part of this you are disputing, or what you are claiming I am assuming.

Comment: Here's where the misunderstanding lies: I said the best one could do *in a typical case* back in the day was to “skim through papers and books”. You are saying that the best one can do *in the best possible case* is have competent librarian. That is why I'm trying to point out to you are arguing against something else than what I claimed (but see also my point 3) from above).

Comment: @alhal Certainly computerized search tools are wonderful, but Selberg's integral strikes me as an excellent illustration of the *limitations* of computerized search tools, rather than an illustration of their *strengths*. Tell me, how would you search for it without knowing that "Selberg" was a relevant search term?

Comment: For comparison, note that human knowledge, and not just pure computer search, played a critical role in unearthing most of the literature on [eigenvectors from eigenvalues](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2022-59-01/S0273-0979-2021-01722-8/home.html). Certain things are still hard to find via pure computer search, even today.

Comment: @alhal I said nothing about the best possible case, and you said nothing about the typical case, these are words that only appear in your most recent comment. It seems you are saying that in the worst case (with your example being Selberg), one does not have access to a librarian. I agree that this is a worst case, but I fail to see how you've demonstrated that the Selberg case is the typical case...?

Comment: @TimothyChow Certainly, but the choice is between having to go yourself some distance to the library (which may not have all the latest journals, as may have been in the 1940s), and (with limited knowledge about potentially equivalent forms of the theorem being formulated in other fields) trying alone to find out what SOTA is (which I think is reasonable to assume is a fairly typical case for mathematicians of the past, though a historian will have to clarify this point, as anecdotal evidence that I could provide -even in this post here Jiaxi would be a good example!- is not that telling) [..]

Comment: VS.  querying most the worlds mathematical knowledge in one click. In that case one is still much better of in the latter case. Of course, if one is well connected to the mathematical community like the authors of the papers you quote, a lot is possible and one can beat basic search by miles. But at the time Selberg wasn't *that* well connected.

Comment: @alhal You haven't answered [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415458/modern-results-that-are-widely-known-yet-which-at-the-time-were-ignored-not-ac/415466?noredirect=1#comment1066576_415466), which is the same as [Will Sawin's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415458/modern-results-that-are-widely-known-yet-which-at-the-time-were-ignored-not-ac/415466?noredirect=1#comment1065659_415466).

Comment: @TimothyChow (at WillSawin & Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda too) Steve Smale: *I used to use libraries, 30 years ago, intensively. I used to just, you know, browse in libraries a huge amount. Now I browse on the Internet.* (source: https://recursed.blogspot.com/2006/02/tucson-day-3-interview-with-steve.html )

Comment: @alhal You're still dodging the question. Why not just admit that you were wrong?

Answer (score 26):

The classification theorem for three-dimensional convex polyhedra known as [Steinitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem) first appeared in a 1922 publication of Ernst Steinitz. Because it did not use the language of graphs it remained obscure until it was given a graph-theoretic formulation in the 1960's.

Comment: That's 100 years ago, so according to the OP it doesn't count... (upvoted, btw).

Comment: Even if it violates my own requirement, I do like it (+1 from me too). It is something different and refreshin than the typical story about Cantor, Grassmann, Galois etc. we usually read about :)

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte I guess we're at the cusp where it matters what month in 1922 it was published (assuming you age results from publication dates).

Comment: Many people at varying stages of aging grimace at the thought of 1922 being a full 100 years ago now :)

Answer (score 23):

The umbral calculus.  Even after Gian-Carlo Rota revived it, its significance was misunderstood by many.  No less a mathematician than Ira Gessel admitted this publicly, in his paper, [Applications of the classical umbral calculus](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00012-003-1813-5) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0108121)).

> When I first encountered umbral notation it seemed to me that this was all there was
> to it; it was simply a notation for dealing with exponential generating functions, or to
> put it bluntly, it was a method for avoiding the use of exponential generating functions
> when they really ought to be used. The point of this paper is that my first impression was
> wrong: none of the results proved here (with the exception of Theorem 7.1, and perhaps
> a few other results in section 7) can be easily proved by straightforward manipulation
> of exponential generating functions.  The sequences that we consider here are defined by
> exponential generating functions, and their most fundamental properties can be proved in
> a straightforward way using these exponential generating functions. What is surprising
> is that these sequences satisfy additional relations whose proofs require other methods.
> The classical umbral calculus is a powerful but specialized tool that can be used to prove
> these more esoteric formulas.

Answer (score 22):

Does acceptance of conjectures before they became theorems count?

Example 1. The Artin reciprocity law.  When Artin went around to other people describing what he was trying to show, nobody else believed it and they laughed at him for thinking it might be true. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243590/on-the-history-of-the-artin-reciprocity-law). This period of non-belief was only 3 years (the time it took Artin from formulation to proof).

Example 2. Modularity of elliptic curves over $\mathbf Q$. The original version by Taniyama in 1955 was expressed too broadly, but after that was fixed up it still took a bit of time for the idea to be generally accepted as plausible. For over 10 years, Shimura believed the conjecture but Weil, Serre, and others did not. See Lang's account of the history of the conjecture [here](https://www.ams.org/notices/199511/forum.pdf).

Weil's identification of the conductor of an elliptic curve over $\mathbf Q$ with the level of the hypothetical associated modular form, in 1967, finally made the conjecture falsifiable and would explain some numerical observations if it were true, e.g., the smallest conductor of an elliptic curve  over $\mathbf Q$ is $11$ and the modularity conjecture would explain this because the modular curve $X_0(N)$ has genus $0$ for all $N < 11$, so no elliptic curve over $\mathbf Q$ could be the image of a morphism from $X_0(N)$ for $N < 11$.

Answer (score 20):

This one technically doesn't fit your stated criteria, but I think it's a good example in the same spirit.  Dan Shechtman's [work on quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Shechtman#Work_on_quasicrystals) was initially strongly resisted, most famously by Linus Pauling, who snidely remarked, "There is no such thing as quasicrystals, only quasi-scientists." [Earlier, similar discoveries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal#History) by other scientists were similarly ignored or dismissed fairly quickly.

In this case, it seems that the mathematical work on aperiodic tilings, though well known and accepted in the mathematical community, was poorly understood or ignored or rejected as irrelevant by most scientists studying crystallography.

Comment: I do like this, even if it falls, as you said, slightly outside of the criteria. :)

Answer (score 12):

J. Howard Redfield anticipated many of the results in "Pólya enumeration" in his 1927 paper in the American Journal of Mathematics (https://doi.org/10.2307/2370675). But this work was largely forgotten until much later (the 1960s): see "The rediscovery of Redfield's papers" by Harary and Robinson (https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190080202).

Answer (score 11):

[Grothendieck's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_inequality), now a fundamental result in functional analysis, with connections to computer science and quantum physics, had a difficult birth.

It was proved by Grothendieck in the paper *Résumé de la théorie métrique des produits tensoriels topologiques*, published in French in 1953 in an obscure Brazilian journal, only in very few copies, making it almost impossible to find.

The paper was almost completely ignored by the community, until it was rediscovered in 1968 by Lindenstrauss and Pelczynski who realized that in particular it contained answers to questions raised **after** its publication.

The story is explained in the first pages of the survey article by Gilles Pisier, [Grothendieck's Theorem, past and present](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4195)

Comment: This is awesome!! +1

Answer (score 10):

My *favorite example* is [Lu Jiaxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Jiaxi_(mathematician))'s work on large sets of disjoint Steiner triple systems and the generalization of Kirkman's schoolgirl problem. Although they might not fit well in the "widely known" criteria. But the story is fascinating anyway.

> His paper on solving the generalized Kirkman's schoolgirl problem was ultimately rejected five years after he wrote them in 1961 and tried to publish them. In April 1979, in some journal issues of 1974 and 1975 that he managed to borrow from Beijing, he unexpectedly learned from a paper of Haim Hanani that the problem which he solved in his 1965 paper had been solved and first published in 1971 by Ray-Chaudhuri and R. M. Wilson, which was a big blow to him.

> He went on to tackle the problem of large sets of disjoint Steiner triple systems. Zhu Lie, a professor of mathematics at Soochow University, realized the importance of his work and suggested that he submit it to the Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A. He wrote to its editorial board that he had essentially solved the problem, and the editors replied to him that if what he said was true, it would be a major achievement.

The Wikipedia article is a bit long and unpolished, with too many unnecessary details. But the overall read was remarkable.

Answer (score 7):

Although more than 100 years old, this is my absolute favourite: Schlaefli's classification of regular polytopes in all dimensions using the Schlafli symbol,
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol.
It was probably not understood at his time, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Schl%C3%A4fli.

Answer (score 5):

Sharkovsky's theorem on the coexistence of periodic cycles for continuous interval maps is a quite obvious example, I think, as the history section of the [Scholarpedia entry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Sharkovsky_ordering#History) explains.

Comment: I have read the Scholarpedia entry, but other than some fiddling about what to put in the abstract at some conference, not too much seem to point to the fact that there was resistance towards this results. Once it was published in English, about 10 years later it seems to already have been popularized (acc. to the History section from the link).

Comment: Yes, it took some 10 years or so for it to generate widespread interest. Looks like you want something more spectacular...

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that any great mathematical discovery made by physicists is at first met with great skepticism by mathematicians until being set on rigorous grounds and then considered with the uttermost respect. From the top of my mind, the Dirac delta function, the Verlinde formula, any mathematical concept with the word *quantum*, *mirror* or *Feynman* in it etc.

The following quote may hint at the problems encountered by mathematicians when it comes to asserting a truth coming from theoretical physics.

```
An absence of proof is a challenge; an absence of definition is deadly.

                                                          Deligne
```

The question asks for examples less than 99 years old but I can't resist mentioning the memoir of Fourier which competed without success for the prize of Academie des sciences, or simply the numerous controversies about infinitesimals at the dawn of modern analysis.

Comment: could you add sources to the claim that any of the things you mentioned were "first met with great skepticism by mathematicians"?

Comment: In my experience, mathematicians are not skeptical of physical research, and don't doubt that these discoveries can be made rigorous. We live in awe of these discoveries. But we also recognize that useful ideas arise from finding rigorous mathematical models of physical discoveries: Hilbert spaces, Lie groups, topological spaces with a precise notion of continuity, Sobolev spaces in which the precise estimates needed to ensure physically realistic behaviour of pde solutions can sometimes be made explicit. It is because we love physics so much that we try to see it so clearly.

Comment: @coudy, I found nothing about mathematicians criticizing Verlinde in the linked article, it only quotes *other physicists* doing so (and not Verlinde formula anyway). Googling "skepticism quantum" produced, for me, mostly links on quantum computing skepticism, which is not a debate about a mathematical concept and hardly a mainstream point of view anyway.

Comment: @McKay I wish I can share your optimism. Searching for "skepticism quantum" on mathoverflow leads for example to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302492/on-mathematical-arguments-against-quantum-computing/302495#302495 which should give explicit examples of mathematicians skeptical about physical (and computer science) research.

Comment: @coudy, no, I did not claim what you ascribe me. In my opinion, the notions of quantum computing are *already* mainstream mathematics. Sorry, I did not mean to quarrel; I simple never heard before, e.g., that there were any serious mathematicians who are/were initially skeptical of all things quantum, and was genuinely curious about where this might come from.

Comment: The word ''quantum'' in a mathematical concept does not imply much to do with physics.

Comment: @coudy I basically agree with what you say, but the question has the word "known" in the title, which to a mathematician means "rigorously proved." So I don't think this answers the question being asked. It answers a slightly different question, which is what *conjectures* were initially greeted with skepticism but which were later rigorously proved?

Answer (score 5):

Heegner's published (1952) solution of Gauss class one problem (stating that there are only 9 imaginary quadratic number fields with class number=1) was not accepted until 1967. Only after Birch, Stark, and Baker (independently) found alternative solutions in 1967, Stark investigated Heegner's work and concluded that it was essentially correct.

Answer (score 4):

A controversial method was Appel & Haken's use of computers in their 1977 proof of the Four Color Theorem that had bested Kempe, Tait, and generations of graph theorists.  There's been a move to formal proof and, with improved computational power, memory, and techniques, results like Heule's determination in 2018 that 161 is the fifth Schur number.  The Computer-assisted proof [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof) is pretty good, and there's a new StackExchange site on this topic on the way.

Comment: I hadn't seen the related discussion between lhf, alhal, and Timothy Chow in the OP comments when I posted this.  The interested reader may want to look at those.

Comment: My summary of that conversation: [alhal questioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415458/modern-results-that-are-widely-known-yet-which-at-the-time-were-ignored-not-ac/415495#comment1065762_415458) whether the four-color theorem is "very useful in the present day." I responded that the proof gave rise to a quadratic-time algorithm that is guaranteed to find a four-coloring of a planar graph. The four-color theorem is also fundamental to current research on [Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)).

Answer (score 1):

Although strictly meanwhile more than 99 years old, a well-known example here
are the [Julia- and Fatou sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set). --
These sets were first investigated by Gaston Julia and Pierre Fatou in 1917/18,
but this work was more-or-less ignored until the invention of computers made it
possible to explore the beauties of these sets, and -- following the works of
[Benoit Mandelbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benoit_Mandelbrot) -- they became widely popularized in the 1980's.

Comment: Disagree. First, there was significant work building on Fatou-Julia theory between 1920 and 1980,  by Joseph Fels Ritt, Kiyoshi Oka, Hubert Cremer, Carl Ludwig Siegel, Irvine Noel Baker and many others (see Alexander, D.S.; Iavernaro, F.; Rosa, A.: Early days in complex dynamics. A history of complex dynamics in one variable during 1906–1942. History of Mathematics, 38. AMS, Providence, RI; LMS, London, 2012.). Second, Fatou and Julia were not there first; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121565/mathematicians-whose-works-were-criticized-by-contemporaries-but-became-widely-a/121657#12165

Comment: @MargaretFriedland Interesting ... ! -- I heard people mentioning this as such example. -- But I am not working on the topic.